# Can you dynamically create a binding property name in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

In Polymer I am creating some `<app-route>` elements in a `<dom-repeat>` as follows:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myItems}}">
  <app-route route="[[_route]]"
             pattern="/view-{{index}}/:data"
             data="{{_routeData}}"
             active="{{_routeActive}}">
  </app-route>
</template>
```

I'd like to use `{{index}}` within the `data` and `active` attribute values to create a dynamic binding property name such as `{{_route{{index}}Data}}` i.e evaluating `{{index}}` when creating the binding name. This would mean that they are unique for each route.

Is it possible to do this in Polymer? If not are there any alternative approaches?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Polymer currently does not support nested bindings as you've described. (For one-way bindings, you could use a [`computed binding`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) (e.g., `data="[[_getRouteData(index)]]"`, but that doesn't apply in your case, as you require an output property.)